# Why can Naruto use Rasengan more than Kakashi using Chidori?

Tags: naruto

Shinobi using Rasengan can often use it more times in a battle as compared to a shinobi using Chidori. Kakashi on one hand, could only use Chidori upto a maximum of four times a day in Part 1. Naruto, however, even when he is using Shadow clones (meaning that he would have only a fraction of the chakra he normally has) still has no trouble using the Rasengan more than that and still have plenty of chakra.

The Rasengan is almost equally, if not more, powerful than the Chidori. So the Rasengan should require the same or more amount of chakra than the Chidori.  Naruto is also said to be very inefficient in using jutsu. So even though he has more chakra than Kakashi, his Rasengan would be less efficient than Kakashi's Chidori. 
I do not believe that Naruto chakra levels are so vast, that even with the use of shadow clones and being inefficient while using jutsu, he can use it multiple times while still retaining plenty of chakra.

So why can Naruto use the Rasengan more than Kakashi using the Chidori?

Comment: He has a bigger chakra pool, naturally.

Comment: Kakashi himself admitted that young Naruto has more chakra than him, while showing Naruto that he can also use Shadow clones.. During the RasenShuriken training episode..

Comment: Expanding on krazer's comment, Naruto is of Uzumaki lineage. And the Uzumaki clan is known for their vast chakra reserves.

Comment: Tajuu Kage Bunshin no Jutsu , kinjutsu(forbidden jutsu), naruto able to perform it before academy graduation perfectly proves that his clone has away more chakra then Kakashi himself. I can't confirm that but IIRC his multiple shadow used rasengan.

Comment: Well!! We are comparing Kakashi with a reincarnation of Ashura Ootsutsuki, the younger son of Hagoromo Ootsutsuki. Also Naruto belongs to Uzumaki clan which is known to have a bigger chakra reserves than other shinobis. Apart from these theories, I'm not sure about the chakra consumption when comparing nature manipulation (chidori) with shape manipulation (rasengan).

Comment: Naruto have bigger chakra pool, Kakashi have smaller than him and he have to use Sharingan in tandem with Chidori and keep alert when he is in Tunnel Vision.

Answer (score 9):

If I recall correctly, at one time, Kakashi commented that Naruto's chakra is about 4 times of what he has. With addition to Kyuubi's chakra, Naruto has about 100 times what Kakashi has. Suppose that Kakashi's chakra is 4, Chidori then costs 1 chakra for each use. Naruto has 4 times what Kakashi has so he has 16. Kage Bunshin actually costs small amount of chakra. The problem with Kage Bunshin is that it splits the chakra of the user which makes it appear as if it costs a lot.

But, when the jutsu is cancelled either by when the Bunshin gets hit, or the caster cancels it, the chakra comes back to the caster along with its experience. Suppose that Naruto doesn't cancel and re-cast Kage Bunshin, there won't be additional chakra cost for casting the jutsu.

Chidori cost = 1

Rasengan cost = 1

Kage Bunshin cost = 0.5 <- assuming it cost lower than Rasengan

Kakashi Chakra = 4

Naruto Chakra = 16

Inefficient chakra usage modifier = 200% (was 125% but changed as per ThatOneGuys's comment)

Kakashi Max Chidori = 4 / 1 = 4

Naruto Max Rasengan = (16 - 0.5 * 200%) / (1 x 200%) = 15 / 2 = 7.5 -> 7 (rounded down)

Without using Kyuubi's chakra, Naruto can do about 2 times more Rasengan than Kakashi can use Chidori. With Kyuubi's chakra, Naruto would be able to do about 100 times more. Of course, since with the training Naruto improved his chakra control, the current Naruto can do more Rasengan than this simple calculation shows.

The reference about Naruto's and Kakashi's chakra pool size and the fact about Kage Bunshin splitting the user's chakra and returning it when the jutsu was cancelled is from the episode where Kakashi train Naruto to develop Rasen Shuriken.

Comment: In one episode Naruto is told that his jutsu are inefficient and this is expressed with a short cartoon comparing Naruto to Sakura and Sasuke using Shadow Clone Jutsu. A bar showed how much chakra was consumed and Naruto's bar was significantly higher than 125% Sakura's and Sasuke's bars. Also Naruto didn't make as many clones as Sakura or Sasuke. Kakashi is even more efficient than Sasuke or Sakura when making Shadow Clones. For example after Zabuza is defeated Kakashi states that he has little chakra left and still produces many clones. I think that 125% is a little bit generous.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but the problem is Naruto without directly using Kyubbis chakra has had mass clones use dozens of Rasengans. Its really one of the few plotholes in the Original series, the numbers do not add up every time.

Comment: He's an Uzumaki, so he already has large chakra reserves to begin with. It's not a plothole.

Answer (score 5):

Naruto not only has a natural vast chakra pool but he has even the Kyuubi supliying him with nearly unlimited chakra amounts.

> and even Kakashi could use the Rasengan pretty easily

Even if in the manga and anime it is stated that Naruto's chakra managament is poor

> because the seal on his belly

After a lot of training and getting rid of some limitations, he improved his chakra management vastly and even learned how to recover chakra in combat.

> thanks to the Sage mode

Plus, it is stated multiple times in the manga/anime that the Rasengan, even though it uses a lot of chakra, isn't comparable on the amount of chakra the Chidori uses. Chakra bending is a lot less taxing than giving an elemental nature to a bending

> Naruto's Rasenshuriken is a Rasengan imbued with his Wind element.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that naruto's humongous power comes from the nine tails chakra that is sealed within him and due to this naruto obviously has more chakra than kakashi due to which he can do more rasengan than kakashi can do chidori

Answer (score 0):

Well Kakashi was making a rough estimate when comparing Naruto's chakra to his own.  First of all by part 2 I'm pretty sure Kakashi's chakra pool had grown to the point that he could make 6 lightning blades each day or a little more.  Plus Rasengan was never said to take up a lot of chakra.  Giant Rasengan was stated to take up more chakra because of its density so I think a lightning blade could be comparable to a giant Rasengan.  But even then Naruto clearly has more than 4 times Kakashi's chakra.  He has made dozens of clones and each could have done multiple Rasengans.

Plus by the time Naruto learns sage mode, Naruto could have done around 6 Rasenshurikens with other Rasengan variants and still not seem to have any noticeable chakra fatigue.  I would say Naruto's chakra reserve is at least 6-8 times that of Kakashi's for him to be able to do so many Rasenshurikens when they take up a lot more chakra than a lightning blade.

Answer (score 0):

It's because The rasengan is an incomplete jutsu. And naruto was the one to perfect it. His dad invented it but never mastered it

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Naruto generally has more chakra; thus can use more jutsu than Kakashi, whos chakra reserves have been getting cut after the fourth war. Naruto has been able to use multiple variants of Rasengan and Rasen-Shuriken more than Kakashi can use a normal Chidori, and its because Naruto's chakra reserves are simply larger than Kakashi's.